# Is this worded correctly if it was spoken in an interview?

Tags: terminology, word-usage, speech

Is this worded correctly if it was spoken in an interview?

> I am like a clean slate.  I do not have any preconceived notions about how the company runs

Comment: Welcome to the site! Is there a specific word or construction you are unsure of?

Comment: I would say that *a clean slate* (or *blank slate*) is such a standard metaphoric cliche that it's probably relative uncommon today to include the word ***like***.

Comment: The phrase clean or blank slate focuses on the future and is derailed by the elaboration focused on present. It is an interesting question that sheds light on the proper usage of the phrase.

Comment: Offhand, I'd say that in an interview you would be better off leading with the thought that you have done your homework and have a pretty good idea, through your research, of what the company's mission and modus operandi are.  Once you've done that you might follow up with the "clean slate" notion in order to highlight your flexibility in adapting to what you infer (perhaps mistakenly) are the company's mission and M.O.

Answer (score 1):

You may have intended to say you have no preconceptions about how you should do your job, which communicates that you can be trained to do it correctly without needing to unlearn a different approach. That is something the interviewer might be happy to hear for employee positions, probably less so if they're hiring for leadership or vision.

The problem with your wording is that the preconception concerns future behavior, where the subject "how the company runs" concerns the present. Being blank on the past or present is ignorance, being blank on the future is potential.

You want to say "I don't have preconceived notions about how X ***should be***" as opposed to commenting on how it is now.

Comment: The question has been (rightly, imho) closed, but I think your point is valid. Personally I would expect my interviewee to have done his homework and actually *know* something about how the company runs before he shows up. It would be no bad thing if he had some idea of how he might fit in, too. Unless you're a glazier, would you really be looking to hire someone who was so keen to tell you he would be [putty in your hands?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22putty+in+your+hands%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: He may have done the homework and simply miscommunicated. It's not inconceivable that a company would rather teach a new hire without prior experience than have to re-educate someone who has already been trained in possibly conflicting methods.